# PHP - DateTime diff() shows 0 months for two dates with one year difference?

Tags: php, datetime, diff, utc

I was running a quick test to help a co-worker with a problem related to dates in PHP using the `DateTime` object.

Surprisingly, when I run this piece of code:

```
namespace Tests\DateTime {
    $date1 = new \DateTime("2013-01-01", new \DateTimeZone("UTC"));
    $date2 = new \DateTime("2014-01-01", new \DateTimeZone("UTC"));
    $interval = $date1->diff($date2);
    print $interval->m;
}
```

I get `0` as the return value. When you use it to measure the different between those two dates within the same year, everything works fine. `1,2,3,4,5, ..., 11` months difference from January to December.

Why is it happening?

Comment: If you want to have months only then, this should be
$monthDiff=$interval->y*12+interval->m;

Comment: if you do var_dump($interval); all will be revealed.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're getting zero because you're only printing the difference in months. You likely want to run your interval through [DateInterval::format](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.format.php).